# Split a string with powershell to get the first and last element

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

If you do: git describe --long

you get: `0.3.1-15-g3b885c5`

Thats the meaning of the above string:

Tag-CommitDistance-CommitId (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)

How would you split the string to get the first (Tag) and last (CommitId) element?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

By using [`String.split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with the  count parameter to manage dashes in the commitid:

```
$x = "0.3.1-15-g3b885c5"
$tag = $x.split("-",3)[0]
$commitid = $x.split("-",3)[-1]
```

Comment: FYI that can be done in a single expression: `$a,$b = "0.3.1-15-g3b885c5".split('-')[0,2]`

Comment: @Richard You are right, I just wanted to show the use `-1` to get the last index.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a `split()` here vs. regex. I like regex, but sometimes a less "sophisticated" solution is better for future readability & maintenance - the original author may understand regex well, but the next person to take on support for the script may not. For more involved text parsing & handling, I go for regex - but for a simple split like this, I stick with `split()`

Comment: We use dot notation for tag and no regex friends here so you get the solution ;-)

Answer (score 15):

**Note**: This answer focuses on improving on the **split-into-tokens-by-`-` approach** from [Richard's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095748/45375), though note that that approach **isn't fully robust**, because `git` tag names may themselves contain `-` characters, so you cannot blindly assume that the first `-` instance ends the tag name.
To account for that, **use [Richard's robust solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095767/45375) instead.**

---

Just to offer a more PowerShell-idiomatic variant:

```sh
# Stores '0.3.1' in $tag, and 'g3b885c5' in $commitId
$tag, $commitId = ('0.3.1-15-g3b885c5' -split '-')[0, -1]
```

- PowerShell's [`-split` *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) is used to split the input string into an array of tokens by separator `-`
  While the `[string]` type's `.Split()` *method* would be sufficient here, [`-split` offers many advantages in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).
- `[0, -1]` extracts the first (`0`) and last (`-1`) element from the array returned by `-split` and returns them as a 2-element array.
- `$tag, $commitId =`  is a destructuring multi-assignment that assigns the elements of the resulting 2-element array to a variable each.

Answer (score 3):

I can't recall if dashes are allowed in tags, so I'll assume they are, but will not appear in the last two fields.

Thus:

```
if ("0.3.1-15-g3b885c5" -match '(.*)-\d+-([^-]+)') {
  $tag = $Matches[1];
  $commitId = $Matches[2]
}
```

Comment: Nicely done; indeed, tag names may contain hyphens (dashes); verify with `git check-ref-format --allow-onelevel '0.3.1-pre.1'; $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0`