# Split a string with spaces on a new line in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a PowerShell script where I take an input of a long string (from a CSV file) in the format:

Group One Name 
Group Two Name 
Group Three Name
...

I'm trying to parse it with

```
($entry.'Group Name').split("`n ") | %{
    if ($_) {
        # Do something with the group name
        $_
    }
}
```

I want to get output like:

Group One Name 
Group Two Name 
Group Three Name 
...

But it comes out as:

Group 
One 
Name 
Group 
Two 
...

Comment: Also, I don't know quite how to format the code in html, so the $ should be $_

Comment: This isn't clear as written. Please show how was `$entry` populated, show the original CSV format, and create a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string argument in [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) is a list of characters to split on, not a sequence of characters to match and then split on.  Your existing code will split on newline, and will split on space.

If you only want to split on newline, use:

```
.split("`n")
```

If you want to split on the character sequence of a newline followed immediately by a space, you can use [`Regex.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[Regex]::Split($entry.'Group Name',"`n ") | ...
```

Alternately, you can use the `-split` operator, which also splits by a string and not a list of characters:

```
$entry.'Group Name' -split "`n "
```

Answer (score 13):

By accepting [Bacon Bits' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41839228/45375) you've indicated that it solves your problem, but that still leaves the question what you *meant* to happen when you passed `` "`n " `` - i.e., a 2-character PowerShell string - to the `[string]` class's [`.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

**This answer makes the case for *routinely* using PowerShell's own [`-split` *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) instead of the [`.Split()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Split)**, because it:

- uses regular PowerShell operator syntax
- offers many more features
- has fewer surprises
- provides long-term behavioral stability

There are **key differences between `-split` and the `.Split()` method**:

- By default, **`-split` uses *regular expressions*** to specify the split criterion; use the `'SimpleMatch'` option as the 3rd RHS argument to use *literal* strings  instead; by contrast, the `.Split()` method *only* accepts literal strings.
- There's also a ***unary* form of `-split`** that splits by any runs of whitespace and ignores leading and trailing whitespace, similar to `awk`'s default behavior; this is equivalent to calling `'...'.Split([string[]] $null, 'RemoveEmptyEntries')`
- **`-split` is case-*insensitive* by default** (as is typical in PowerShell); use the `-csplit` form for case-sensitive matching; by contrast, `.Split()` is *invariably* case-*sensitive*.
- **`-split` accepts an *array-valued* LHS**, returning a *concatenation* of the token arrays resulting from splitting the LHS's elements.
- **`-split` *implicitly* converts the LHS to string(s)**; by contrast, `.Split()` can only be invoked on something that already is a `[string]`.

Note: *Both* `-split` and `.Split()` allow you to limit the number of tokens returned with an optional 2nd argument, which only splits *part* of the input string, reporting the rest of the input string in the last element of the return array.

For the full story, see [`Get-Help about_Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split).

The **`.Split()` method has one advantage**, though: **it is *faster*** than the `-split` operator; so, *if* `.Split()`'s features are sufficient in a given scenario, you can speed things up with it.

**Examples:**

<sup>Note: In the examples below that use regular expressions, *single-quoted* strings are used, with LF characters represented as *regular-expression escape sequence* `\n` rather than the `` `n `` escape sequences PowerShell supports in any *double-quoted* strings, because it is preferable to specify regular expressions as *single-quoted* strings, to avoid confusion between what PowerShell expands up front and what `-split` ends up seeing.</sup>

- **Split by *any* in a *set* of *characters***, as a regular expression: `` "`n" `` (LF) *and also* `" "` (single space):

  - `` "one two`n three four" -split '[\n ]' `` yields the equivalent of
    `@( 'one', 'two', '', 'three', 'four' )`
- **Split by a *string***, specified as a *regular expression*: `` "`n " ``:

  - `` "one two`n three four" -split '\n ' `` yields the equivalent of
    `@( 'one two', 'three four' )`
- **Split by a *string literal***: `` "`n " ``, using the `SimpleMatch` option:

  - `` "one two`n three four" -split "`n ", 0, 'SimpleMatch' `` yields the same as above; note that `0` is the number-of-tokens-to-return argument, which must be specified for syntax reasons here; `0` indicates that *all* tokens should be returned.
- **Use *capture groups* (`(...)`) in the separator regex to include (parts of) separators** in the result array:

  - `'a/b' -split '(/)'` yields the equivalent of `@('a', '/', 'b')`
  - Alternatively, use a ***positive lookahead assertion* (`(?=...)`)** to **make the separators part of the elements**: `'a/b/c' -split '(?=/)'` yields the equivalent of
    `@( 'a', '/b', '/c' )`
- **Limit the number of tokens**:

  - `'one two three four' -split ' ', 3` yields the equivalent of
    `@( 'one', 'two', 'three four' )`, i.e., the 3rd token received the remainder of the input string.
  - *Caveat*: elements that are (parts of) separators captured via a capture group in the separator regex do *not* count toward the specified limit; e.g.,
    `'a/b/c' -split '(/)', 2` yields `@( 'a', '/', 'b/c' )`, i.e. *3* elements in total.
- **Split by any run of whitespace (unary form)**:

  - `` -split "`n  one   `n`n two `t  `t three`n`n" `` yields the equivalent of
    `@( 'one', 'two', 'three' )`

---

#### `String.Split()`-method pitfalls:

Having access to the .NET Framework's method *if needed* is a wonderful option that allows you to do in PowerShell most of what compiled .NET languages can do.
However, there are things that PowerShell has to do behind the scenes that are typically helpful, but can also be *pitfalls*:

For instance, `` 'foo'.Split("`n ") `` causes PowerShell to implicitly convert the *string* `` "`n " `` to a *character array* (`[char[]]`) before calling `.Split()` (the closest match among the method overloads), which may be unexpected.

Your intent may have been to split by *string* `` "`n " ``, but the method overload invoked ended up interpreting your string as a a *set of individual characters* any one of which to split the input by.

Incidentally, the cross-platform PowerShell *Core* edition has an additional `.Split()` overload that *does* now directly take a `[string]` argument, so the same call behaves differently there.

*This changing behavior outside the control of PowerShell is in itself a good reason to prefer PowerShell-only solutions* - for an explanation of why such changes are outside PowerShell's control, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11720#issuecomment-579866445).

You *can* avoid such pitfalls by explicit typing, but that is both cumbersome and easy to forget.
Case in point:

In *Windows* PowerShell, if you truly wanted to split by *string* `` "`n " ``, this is what you'd need to do:

```
PS> "one`n two".Split([string[]] "`n ", 'None')
one
two
```

Note the necessary cast to `[string[]]` - even though only *one* string is passed - and the required use of the option parameter (`None`).

Conversely, if you wanted to split by a *set of characters* in PowerShell *Core*:

```
PS> "one`ntwo three".Split([char[]] "`n ")
one
two
three
```

Without the `[char[]]` cast, `` "`n " `` would be considered a *single string* to split by.

Comment: Well, there's another good reason for using `.Split` _sometimes_: it can lead to nicer-looking code. Say I have a `$url` variable and I want to grab everything after the last `/`. With `-split` it would be `($url -split '/')[-1]` – but, with `.Split` it would be `$url.Split('/')[-1]` ... Plus, it can also help prevent nesting parentheses; for example, if I then wanted to also snip off the extension: `(($url -split '/')[-1] -split '\.',2)[0]` vs. `$url.Split('/')[-1].Split('.',2)[0]`

Comment: @Vopel, yes, method chaining is nice, if `.Split()` is appropriate in a given situation (literal, case-sensitive splitting); you may prefer it also for performance reasons, but not every PowerShell user is necessarily comfortable with the different rules of method syntax.

Comment: @mkelement0 I know there's a lot of people with that line of thinking, but from my perspective, not taking advantage of having integrated .NET is like forsaking half the shell.

Comment: @Vopel, that is a [false dichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma): Primarily, pointing out _PowerShell-native_ solutions is important: _If available_ (and unless performance dictates otherwise), such solutions require only mastering _one_ knowledge domain: that of PowerShell itself. _Otherwise_ - and alternatively _always_ to those familiar with C# / direct use of .NET APIs - the _option_ to call .NET APIs _directly_ - which invariable requires knowledge of an _additional_ domain - is a wonderful option to have, and having that option is what makes PowerShell unique among shells

Comment: @mkelement0 Perhaps I didn't do a good enough job conveying what I meant, because you pretty much just described what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading correctly, your call to `.Split` is passing in both `` `n `` and the space character. So, you are actually asking PowerShell to turn a string like `"Group One Name"` into a list like `@("Group", "One", "Name")`.

If `$entry` is a single record, and you are running this line once for each of "Group One Name", "Group Two Name" and "Group Three Name", then you probably don't need the call to `.Split` at all -- simply use `$entry.'Group Name'` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a **switch** statement. Personally, I reckon using one would make your code more readable/maintainable:

```
[System.Array] $arrCSVData = @();

$arrCSVData = Import-CSV -LiteralPath '---your .csv path ---';

switch ( $arrCSVData ) {

    { $_.'Group Name' -eq 'Group One Name' } {
        # Do something with group #1.
        break;
        }

    { $_.'Group Name' -eq 'Group Two Name' } {
        # Do something with group #2.
        break;
        }

    } #switch
```

This is obviously lacking error handling for the CSV import...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only need to remove space from the existing code.

```
.split("`n ")
```

should be:

```
.split("`n")
```

Existing code uses both *new line* and *space* as delimiters for splitting the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `r Windows escape character for a line return.