# Pass a single space-delimited string as multiple arguments

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing, destructuring

I have a Powershell function in which I am trying to allow the user to add or remove items from a list by typing the word "add" or "remove" followed by a space-delimited list of items.  I have an example below (slightly edited, so you can just drop the code into a powershell prompt to test it "live").

```
$Script:ServerList = @("Server01","Server02","Server03")
Function EditServerList (){
$Script:ServerList = $Script:ServerList |Sort -Unique
Write-host -ForegroundColor Green $Script:ServerList
$Inputs = $args
If ($Inputs[0] -eq "start"){
    $Edits =  Read-Host "Enter `"add`" or `"remove`" followed by a space-delimited list of server names"
    #"# EditServerList $Edits
    #   EditServerList $Edits.split(' ')
    EditServerList ($Edits.split(' ') |Where {$_ -NotLike "add","remove"})
    EditServerList start
} Elseif ($Inputs[0] -eq "add"){
    $Script:ServerList += $Inputs |where {$_ -NotLike $Inputs[0]}
    EditServerList start
} Elseif ($Inputs[0] -eq "remove"){
    $Script:ServerList = $Script:ServerList |Where {$_ -NotLike ($Inputs |Where {$_ -Notlike $Inputs[0]})}
    EditServerList start
} Else {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "ERROR!"
    EditServerList start
}
}
EditServerList start
```

As you can see, the function takes in a list of arguments.  The first argument is evaluated in the If/Then statements and then the rest of the arguments are treated as items to add or remove from the list.

I have tried a few different approaches to this, which you can see commented out in the first IF evaluation.

I have two problems.

1. When I put in something like "add Server05 Server06" (without quotes) it works, but it also drops in the word "add".
2. When I put in "remove Server02 Server03" (without quotes) it does not edit the array at all.

Can anybody point out where I'm going wrong, or suggest a better approach to this?

Answer (score 2):

To address the *title*'s generic question up front:

- When you pass an *array* to a function (and nothing else), `$Args` receives a *single* argument *containing the whole array*, so you must use `$Args[0]` to access it.

  - There *is* a way to pass an array as individual arguments using *splatting*, but it requires an intermediate variable - see bottom.
- To avoid confusion around such issues, formally declare your parameters.

---

Try the following:

```
$Script:ServerList = @("Server01", "Server02", "Server03")

Function EditServerList () {
  # Split the arguments, which are all contained in $Args[0],
  # into the command (1st token) and the remaining
  # elements (as an array).
  $Cmd, $Servers = $Args[0]
  If ($Cmd -eq "start"){
    While ($true) {
      Write-host -ForegroundColor Green $Script:ServerList
      $Edits =  Read-Host "Enter `"add`" or `"remove`" followed by a space-delimited list of server names"
      #"# Pass the array of whitespace-separated tokens to the recursive
      # invocation to perform the requested edit operation.
      EditServerList (-split $Edits)
    }
  } ElseIf ($Cmd -eq "add") {
    # Append the $Servers array to the list, weeding out duplicates and
    # keeping the list sorted.
    $Script:ServerList = $Script:ServerList + $Servers | Sort-Object -Unique
  } ElseIf ($Cmd -eq "remove") {
    # Remove all specified $Servers from the list.
    # Note that servers that don't exist in the list are quietly ignored.
    $Script:ServerList = $Script:ServerList | Where-Object { $_ -notin $Servers }
  } Else {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "ERROR!"
  }
}

EditServerList start
```

- Note how a *loop* is used inside the `"start"` branch to avoid running out of stack space, which could happen if you keep *recursing*.
- `$Cmd, $Servers = $Args[0]` destructures the array of arguments (contained in the one and only argument that was passed - see below) into the 1st token - (command string `add` or `remove`) and the array of the remaining arguments (server names).

  - Separating the arguments into command and server-name array up front simplifies the remaining code.
  - The `$var1, $var2 = <array>` technique to split the RHS into its *first element* - assigned as a *scalar* to `$var1` - and the *remaining elements* - assigned as an *array* to `$var2`, is commonly called *destructuring* or *unpacking*; it is documented in [`Get-Help about_Assignment Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators#assigning-multiple-variables), albeit without giving it such a name.
- `-split $Edits` uses the convenient *unary* form of the `-split` operator to break the user input into an array of whitespace-separated token and passes that array to the recursive invocation.

  - Note that `EditServerList (-split $Edits)` passes a *single* argument that is an *array* - which is why `$Args[0]` must be used to access it.
  - Using PowerShell's `-split` operator (as opposed to `.Split(' ')`) has the added advantage of ignoring leading and trailing whitespace and ignoring multiple spaces between entries.
    In general, operator `-split` is preferable to the `[string]` type's `.Split()` method - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375) of mine.
- Not how containment operator `-notin`, which accepts an array as the RHS, is used in `Where-Object { $_ -notin $Servers }` in order to filter out values from the server list contained in `$Servers`.

---

As for **what you tried:**

- `EditServerList ($Edits.split(' ') |Where {$_ -NotLike "add","remove"})` (a) mistakenly *attempts* to remove the command name from the argument array, even though the recursive invocations require it, but (b) actually *fails* to do so, because the RHS of `-like` doesn't support *arrays*. (As an aside: since you're looking for *exact* strings, `-eq` would have been the better choice.)
- Since you're passing the arguments as an *array* as the *first and only* argument, `$Inputs[0]` actually refers to the *entire array* (command name + server names), not just to its first element (the command name).

  - You got away with `($Inputs[0] -eq "add")` - even though the entire *array* was compared - because the `-eq` operator performs *array filtering* if its LHS is an array, returning a sub-array of matching elements. Since `add` was *among* the elements, a 1-element sub-array was returned, which, in a *Boolean* context, is "truthy".
  - However, your attempt to weed out the command name with `where {$_ -NotLike $Inputs[0]}` then failed, and `add` was *not* removed - you'd actually have to compare to `$Inputs[0][0]` (sic).
- `Where {$_ -NotLike ($Inputs |Where {$_ -Notlike $Inputs[0]})}` doesn't filter anything out for the following reasons:

  - `($Inputs |Where {$_ -Notlike $Inputs[0]})` always returns an *empty array*, because, the RHS of `-Notlike` is an *array*, which, as stated, doesn't work.
  - Therefore, the command is the equivalent of `Where {$_ -NotLike @() }` which returns `$True` for *any* scalar on the LHS.

---

#### Passing an array as individual arguments using *splatting*

Argument *splatting* (see [`Get-Help about_Splatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)) works with arrays, too:

```
> function foo { $Args.Count } # function that outputs the argument count.

> foo @(1, 2)  # pass array
1  # single parameter, containing array

> $arr = @(1, 2); foo @arr # splatting: array elements are passed as indiv. args.
2
```

Note how an *intermediate variable* is required, and how it must be prefixed with `@` rather than `$` to perform the splatting.

Comment: Hi mklement0,
First, off, thanks for the very detailed answer.  I appreciate the thought you put into your response.
 
Can you help me understand a bit more what's going on with the following line you posted?
 
$Cmd, $Servers = $Args[0]
 
With two variables on the left of $Args[0], is the effect that $Cmd takes on $Args[0] and $Servers takes on the rest of the array?  Meaning that if I were to put in the following...
 
$Cmd1, $Cmd2, $Servers = $Args[0]
 
...that $Cmd1 would get $Args[0], $Cmd2 would get $Args[1], and $Servers woudl get whatever is left?

Comment: @JDDellGuy: My pleasure; you are correct about how the assignment works; please see my update, which added an explanation and a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use parameters to modify the ServerList, this way you can use a single line to both add and remove:

```
Function EditServerList {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$ServerList,
        [array]$add,
        [array]$remove
    )

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "ServerList Contains: $ServerList"

    $Servers = $ServerList.split(' ')

    if ($add) {
        $Servers += $add.split(' ')
    }

    if ($remove) {
        $Servers = $Servers | Where-Object { $remove.split(' ') -notcontains $_ }
    }

    return $Servers
}
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
EditServerList -ServerList "Server01 Server02 Server03" -remove "Server02 Server03" -add "Server09 Server10"
```

Which will return:

```
Server01
Server09
Server10
```