# Split & Trim in a single step

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, text-parsing

In PS 5.0 I can split and trim a string in a single line, like this

```
$string = 'One, Two, Three'
$array = ($string.Split(',')).Trim()
```

But that fails in PS 2.0. I can of course do a foreach to trim each item, or replace `', '` with `','` before doing the split, but I wonder if there is a more elegant approach that works in all versions of PowerShell?
Failing that, the replace seems like the best approach to address all versions with a single code base.

Comment: You could use the RegEx version of split like `$array = $string -split ', *'` to remove any spaces following the commas.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

Use the `-split` *operator*, which works the same in **PSv2**: It expects a *regular expression* (regex) as the separator, allowing for more sophisticated tokenizing than the `[string]` type's `.Split()` *method*, which operates on *literals*:

```bash
PS> 'One, Two, Three' -split ',\s*' | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }
[One]
[Two]
[Three]
```

Regex `,\s*` splits the input string by a comma followed by zero or more (`*`) whitespace characters (`\s`).

In fact, [choosing `-split` over `.Split()` is advisable in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375), even in later PowerShell versions.

---

However, to be fully equivalent to the `.Trim()`-based solution in the question, trimming of leading and trailing whitespace is needed too:

```bash
PS> ' One,   Two,Three  ' -split ',' -replace '^\s+|\s+$' | ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }
[One]
[Two]
[Three]
```

`-replace '^\s+|\s+$'` removes the leading and trailing whitespace from each token resulting from the split: `|` specifies an *alternation* so that the subexpressions on either side of it are considered a match; `^\s+,` matches leading whitespace, `\s+$` matches trailing whitespace; `\s+` represents a *non-empty* (one or more, `+`) run of whitespace characters; for more information about the `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

In **PSv3+**, you could simplify to:

```bash
(' One,   Two,Three  ' -split ',').Trim()
```

or use the solution shown in the question.
Both solutions rely on a v3+ feature called *member-access enumeration*, discussed below.

To also weed out empty / all-whitespace elements, append `-ne ''`

---

As for **why `('One, Two, Three'.Split(',')).Trim()` doesn't work in PSv2**: The `.Split()` method returns an *array* of tokens, and invoking the `.Trim()` method on that array - as opposed to its elements - isn't supported in PSv2.

In PSv3+, the `.Trim()` method call is implicitly "forwarded" to the *elements* of the resulting array, resulting in the desired trimming of the individual tokens - this feature is called [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

Comment: You may also want to explicitly filter empty values so you can handle empty input values, or extra commas.

For example, `("" -split ",").Trim()` returns an array with an empty string while `("" -split ",").Trim() | where {$_ -ne ''}` returns an empty array. In a similar way, `(" ,One, Two,, Three, ," -split ",").Trim() | where {$_ -ne ''}` will return an array with three elements with no empty strings

Comment: @JoseLamasRíos, good idea. Note that instead of `| where { $_ -ne '' }` you can simply use `-ne ''`, relying on the array-filtering capabilities of PowerShell's operators; I've added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have PS 2.0 but you might try something like

```
$string = 'One, Two, Three'
$array = ($string.Split(',') | % { $_.Trim() })
```

and see if that suits.  This is probably less help for you but for future readers who have moved to future versions you can use the `#Requires` statement.  See `help about_Requires` to determine if your platforms supports this feature.

Comment: +1 for the correct to-v2 translation of the code in the question, but note that Gordon is specifically looking for a more elegant solution ("I can of course do a foreach to trim each item [...]").

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [@mkelement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52013903), there's another handy trick you can do thanks to the way comparison operators handle collections:

```
$strings = ' One,   Two,Three  ' -split ',|\s' -ne ''

# Proof of no whitespace:
$strings -notmatch '\s'
```

*Output*:

```
One
Two
Three
```