# How to find data and replace variable in PowerShell Command

Tags: powershell

I currently have a series of Dyanmic Distribution Groups that I want to edit the recipient filter on. Our company is based by location number, which is a 4 digit number. This number is part of the display name of the dynamic distribution group...example webcontact_1234_DG....1234 would be the 4 digit center number. I am wanting to replace the recipient filter to have office -eq (1234) but have it pull the number from the display name. All display names are going to be the same number of characters before the 4 digit center number, for example, webcontact_1234_DG, webcontact_2345_DG, webcontact_3456_DG, etc.

I have a replace code but it changed the office location to null.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
$groups=Get-DynamicDistributionGroup -filter {alias -like "webcontact*"}
foreach ($group in $groups) {
     $locationcode=$($group.alias).tostring.replace("\\D", "")
     set-dynamicdistributiongroup $group -recipientfilter {((((office -eq $locationcode) -and
      (have the recipent filter here but can't display due to confidential information) -and
      (RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and
      (-not(RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'RoomMailbox')) -and
      (-not(RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'SharedMailbox'))))}
}
```

Comment: So you want to use the 4 digit value within the display name to change the office field of said contact?

Comment: As an aside: It's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best answer I can come up with based on the given information. I assume you are having a problem getting that number out of your `webcontact_1234_DG`, I would use regex to get those numbers out and into another variable.

```
$locationcode = [regex]::Match($group.alias,'^[^_]+_([^_]+)_[^_]+$').Groups[1].Value
```

The above code will grab everything in between the two underscores.

Try that and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to **use the `-split` operator** to extract the number (text) from your values<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
$locationcode = ($group.Alias -split '_')[1]
```

`-split '_'` returns the array of tokens that result when you split the input string by `_` chars., and `[1]` returns the 2nd token, which is the desired location number.

Simple example:

```
PS> ('webcontact_3456_DG' -split '_')[1]
3456
```

Alternatively, a corrected version of your own attempt (see below) would use the **`-replace` operator**:

```
PS> 'webcontact_3456_DG' -replace '\D' # remove all non-digit chars.
3456
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```
> $($group.alias).tostring.replace("\\D", "")
> ```

- The `[string]` type's `.Replace()` searches by *literal* strings, so the search for `\\D` in your names will fail, and no replacement will occur.

  - Additionally, note that PowerShell's escape character is `` ` `` (backtick), not `\`, and that `\` therefore doesn't require escaping: in PowerShell `"\\D"` literally becomes `\\D`.
- As an aside: There is generally no need to put `$(...)` around expressions.

---

<sup>[1] You could also use the `[string]` type's `.Split()` .NET *method* in this simple case, but [I suggest using the far more flexible `-split` PS *operator* as a matter of habit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).</sup>