# PowerShell Regular Expression match Y or Z

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to match some strings using a regular expression in PowerShell but due to the differing format of the original string that I'm extracting from, encountering difficulty. I admittedly am not very strong with creating regular expressions.

I need to extract the numbers from each of these strings. These can vary in length but in both cases will be preceded by `Foo`

```
PC1-FOO1234567
PC2-FOO1234567/FOO98765
```

This works for the second example:

`'PC2-FOO1234567/FOO98765' -match 'FOO(.*?)\/FOO(.*?)\z'`

It lets me access the matched strings using `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]` which is great.

It obviously doesn't work for the first example. I suspect I need some way to match on either `/` or the end of the string but I'm not sure how to do this and end up with my desired match.

Suggestions?

Comment: Use `'FOO(.*?)(?:/FOO(.*))?$'`

Comment: As an aside: It is only in languages that use `/.../` for regex literals that you need to escape `/` as `\/` (PowerShell is not one of them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
'FOO(.*?)(?:/FOO(.*))?$'
```

It will match `FOO`, then capture any 0 or more chars as few as possible into Group 1 and then will attempt to optionally match a sequence of patterns: `/FOO`, any 0 or more chars as many as possible captured into Group 2 and then the end of string position should follow.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=FOO%28.*%3F%29%28%3F%3A%2FFOO%28.*%29%29%3F%24&i=PC1-FOO1234567%0D%0APC2-FOO1234567%2FFOO98765&o=m)

**Details**

- `FOO` - literal substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than newline, as few as possible
- `(?:/FOO(.*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 repetitions of:

  - `/FOO` - a literal substring
  - `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than newline as many as possible (`*` is greedy)
- `$` - end of string.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*[edit - removed the unneeded pipe to `Where-Object`. thanks to mklement0 for that! [*grin*]]*

this is a somewhat different approach. it splits on the `foo`, then replaces the unwanted `/` with nothing, and finally filters out any string that contains letters.

the pure regex solutions others offered will likely be faster, but this may be slightly easier to understand - and therefore to maintain. [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
PC1-FOO1234567
PC2-FOO1234567/FOO98765
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$InStuff -split 'foo' -replace '/' -notmatch '[a-z]'
```

output ...

```
1234567
1234567
98765
```

Answer (score 2):

To offer a more concise **alternative with the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) operator**, which obviates the need to access `$Matches` afterwards to extract the numbers:

```
PS> 'PC1-FOO1234568', 'PC2-FOO1234567/FOO98765' -split '(?:^PC\d+-|/)FOO' -ne ''
1234568  # single match from 1st input string
1234567  # first of 2 matches from 2nd input string
98765
```

Note: `-split` always returns a `[string[]]` array, even if only 1 string is returned; result strings from multiple input strings are combined into a single, flat array.

- `^PC\d+-|/` matches `PC` followed by 1 or more (`+`) digits (`\d`) at the start of the string (`^`) *or* (`|`) a `/` char., which matches both `PC2-FOO` at the beginning and `/FOO`.

  - `(?:...)`, a *non-capturing* subexpression, must be used to prevent `-split` from including what the subexpression matched in the results array.
- `-ne ''` filters out the *empty* elements that result from the input strings *starting* with a separator.

---

<sup>To learn more about the regex-based `-split` operator and in what ways it is more powerful than the string literal-based .NET `String.Split()` method, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).</sup>