# Rename files by reformatting the date string embedded in their names

Tags: powershell, replace, file-rename

I am using Windows' Powershell in the CMD to remove 'Mon, tue, wed' etc. from my filenames, which works perfectly

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ $_.replace("Mon ", "") }
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ $_.replace("Tue ", "") }
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ $_.replace("Wed ", "") }
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ $_.replace("Thur ", "") }
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ $_.replace("Fri ", "") }
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ $_.replace("Sat ", "") }
```

Now my file names look like this:
13 July 2018 - Lorem ipsum

I would like to switch the day with the month, so it will be: 
July 13 2018, so I could sort it by month. Or maybe even 2018 July 13.

How could I do this?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Why not parse the date and re-output it in YYYY-MM-DD format? Months as names will not be (usefully) sortable.

Comment: Well they are downloaded files from the interwebz, which have the date of the blogarticle in the filename. So I would like to keep it simple and just switch the months and year etc. So I can sort it easily in my folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **combine both desired transformations into a *single* operation** using `Rename-Item` with a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) in which the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator) allows you to transform the file name as needed based on a *regex* (regular expression).

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name | Rename-Item -NewName {
  $_.Name -replace '\w+ (\d+) (\w+) (\d+)', '$3 $2 $1'
} -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the renaming operation; remove it to perform actual renaming.</sup>

An input file named `Mon 13 July 2018 - Lorem ipsum`, for instance, would be renamed to 
`2018 July 13 - Lorem ipsum`.

<sup>Note: This sample file name happens to have no filename extension, but both the solutions above and below equally work with file names that do have extensions.</sup>

For more information about PowerShell's `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

---

If you wanted **make your filenames truly sortable** using an embedded format such as `2018-07-13` to represent `13 July 2018`, more work is needed, via the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name | Rename-Item -NewName {
  # Split the name into the date part (ignoring the weekday) and the
  # rest of the file name.
  $null, $date, $rest = $_.Name -split '\w+ (\d+ \w+ \d+)'
  # Convert the date string to [datetime] instance, reformat it, and
  # append the rest.
  ([datetime] $date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') + $rest
} -WhatIf
```

An input file named `Mon 13 July 2018 - Lorem ipsum`, for instance, would be renamed to 
`2018-07-13 - Lorem ipsum`.

For more information about PowerShell's `-split` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).
Assigning to *multiple* variables (`$null, $date, $rest = ...`) is explained in help topic [about_Assignment_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-6#assigning-multiple-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question, IMO mklement0's answer serves best.

But a replacement for your <s>ugly</s> suboptimal sample code.

The RegEx based -replace operator is superior to the .replace() method
when having alternations to replace.

```
[Globalization.DatetimeFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames
```

returns the abbreviated Day Names for the current locale, which can be combined
in one RegEx `"(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat) "` with the code

```
$RE=[regex]"("+([Globalization.DatetimeFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames -join '|')+") "

Get-ChildItem -recurse -File | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $RE} -WhatIf
```

An empty replacement string doesn't need to expressed with the -replace operator.

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing -WhatIf

Answer (score 0):

You could chain replacements for each month and end with a replace statement to switch the numbers like this

```
"13 July 2018 - Lorem ipsum" `
    -replace 'July', '07' `
    -replace 'Aug', '08' `
    -replace "(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)", '$3 $2 $1'
```

wich returns

```
2018 07 13 - Lorem ipsum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to convert the date

```
$string = '13 July 2018 - Lorem ipsum'
$dateObject = [datetime]$string.Split('-')[0]
Write-Output "$($dateObject.ToString('yyyy MMMM dd')) - $($array[1])"
```

This will output

```
2018 July 13 -  Lorem ipsum
```