# Can I use split on a string two times in a row using piping?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have the following string `dog.puppy/cat.kitten/bear.cub`. I want to get `bear` only. I can do this by executing the following:

```
$str = "dog.puppy/cat.kitten/bear.cub"
$str = $str.split('/')[2]
$str = $str.split('.')[0]
```

Am I able to get `bear` using one line using piping? This doesn't work, but it would be something like this:

```
$str = "dog.puppy/cat.kitten/bear.cub"
$str = $str.split('/')[2] | $_.split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$str = "dog.puppy/cat.kitten/bear.cub".split('/')[2].split('.')[0]
```

No piping needed.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Next I need to split the string based on capital letters, so let's say the string was `dog.puppy/cat.kitten/bearOneTwoThree.cub`, and I need the result `bear One Two Three` which is achieved using -creplace ".(?=[^a-z])", "$& ". Am I able to do this in one line?

Comment: I suggest opening a separate question for that, and simplify the question to only use the `bearOneTwoThree` text.

Comment: I just figured it out. I just had to do `$str = $str.split('/')[2].split('.')[0] | ForEach-object { $_ -creplace '.(?=[^a-z])','$& ' }`

Answer (score 4):

> Am I able to get "bear" using one line *using piping*?

With **strings already stored in memory, there is *no* good reason to use the *pipeline*** - it will only slow things down.

Instead, **use PowerShell's *operators***, which are **faster than using a pipeline** and generally **more flexible than** the similarly named **.NET `[string]` type's *methods***, because they **operate on *regexes*** (regular expressions) and can also operate on *entire arrays*:

```
PS> ('dog.puppy/cat.kitten/bear.cub' -split '[/.]')[-2]
bear
```

That is, split the input string by either literal `/` or literal `.` (using a character set, `[...]`), and return the penultimate (second to last) (`[-2]`) token.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375) for why you should generally prefer the [`-split` *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) to the [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) *method*, for instance.
The same applies analogously to preferring the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) to the [`String.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace) method.

---

It's easy to ***chain* these operators**:

```
PS> ('dog.puppy/cat.kitten/bearOneTwoThree.cub' -split '[/.]')[-2] -csplit '(?=\p{Lu})'
bear
One
Two
Three
```

That is, return the penultimate token and split it case-*sensitively* (using the `-csplit` variation of the `-split` operator) whenever an uppercase letter (`\p{Lu}`) starts, using a [positive look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), `(?=...`).

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier solution,
the `.split()` method uses each char to split,
using a negative index counts from back, so

```
> "dog.puppy/cat.kitten/bear.cub".split( '/.')[-2]
bear
```

Your other question can be solved with the RegEx based `-csplit` operator using a
[nonconsuming positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and
a final `-join ' '` to concatenate the array elements with a space.

```
$str = "dog.puppy/cat.kitten/bearOneTwoThree.cub"
$str = $str.split('/.')[-2] -csplit '(?=[A-Z])' -join ' '
$str
bear One Two Three
```

Comment: It's unfortunate, but to make your `.Split()` call work in PowerShell _Core_ as well, you must use `"dog.puppy/cat.kitten/bear.cub".split([char[]] '/.')[-2]` - see the (updated) bottom section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375 for an explanation (and thanks for the recent edit there).