# How do I capture the 2nd match for each line?

Tags: regex, powershell, syntax-highlighting

Basically, I need to match with 1 per line but right now, my regex is matching 2 per line.

https://regex101.com/r/KmgGwS/8

My regex is looking for 2 slashes  and it returns the string in between but the problem is my path has multiple slashes and I only need to match it with the 2nd match per each line

```regex
(?<=\\).*?(?=\\)
```

This is my PowerShell code:

```
if ( $_.PSPath -match ("(?<=::).*?(?=\\)")) {
    $user = $matches.Values
}
```

For example:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\Root\CDD4EEAE6000AC7F40C3802C171E30148030C072
Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\Root\BE36A4562FB2EE05DBB3D32323ADF445084ED656
```

What my code does is it gets

```
Certificate::CurrentUserRoot
Certificate::CurrentUserRoot
```

but what I only really need is get the string to the 2nd match \ ___\ which is:

```
Root
Root
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string. Repeat 2 times matching not a backslash or a newline followed by a backslash.

Use a capturing group to match what follows;

```
^[^\\\r\n]*\\[^\\\r\n]*\\([^\\\r\n]+)
```

*About the pattern*

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\\\r\n]*\\[^\\\r\n]*\\` Match 2 times not `\` or a newline, then `\`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^\\\r\n]+` Match 1+ times not `\` or a newline
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XunG6C/1) | [Try it online](https://tio.run/##TY7BCoJAFEXX@RUiLbRQnikp7WKyXRRJtPAVyPCkgXJkfBIRfbtli2h3Lgcup9F3Mu2Frte@V5XrbJQ0utUVB7vB5IMJcpKdUfxAQYZVpWTJtFiIzhiq@dCSwb3WjGK1irNsmc0BYCmSdQwiSmEmwiTMIgjjFCIQkMwc27@VLC@265yLMyIarE8TxH92f2PqOZ5nPa3R8ZNA/rbjpmN7/H2gtghP1qvv3w)

The value is in the first capturing group:

```
$user = $matches[1]
```

If you want the match only to use your script instead of group 1, you could make use of a positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is 2 times not `\` followed by `\`

```
(?<=^[^\\\r\n]*\\[^\\\r\n]*\\)[^\\\r\n]+
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5b%5e%5c%5c%5cr%5cn%5d*%5c%5c%5b%5e%5c%5c%5cr%5cn%5d*%5c%5c%29%5b%5e%5c%5c%5cr%5cn%5d%2b&i=Microsoft.PowerShell.Security%5cCertificate%3a%3aCurrentUser%5cRoot%5cCDD4EEAE6000AC7F40C3802C171E30148030C072%0d%0aMicrosoft.PowerShell.Security%5cCertificate%3a%3aCurrentUser%5cRoot%5cBE36A4562FB2EE05DBB3D32323ADF445084ED656%0d%0aMicrosoft.PowerShell.Security%5cCertificate%3a%3aCurrentUser%5cRoot%5cA43489159A520F0D93D032CCAF37E7FE20A8B419&o=m) | [Try it online](https://tio.run/##TY7NCoJAFEbX@RQiLbRIrikZUURMtouiqBbdApErDVgTM3eIiJ7dfhbR7nwc@DhXdSNtTlRVdS1L35vLQiujSg6XH7P@mHBNhdWS7yhIsyxlkTMNBsJqTRfeGNK4UopRTKdJlk2yHgBMRDpLQMR96IoojbIYoqQPMQhIu57bOedcnFzf88fD0XF/RESNl0ML8Z@D32h7QeA8nMbuXUGdheWrZbf5PSETbvPKknGedf0C)

Comment: Thank you. This one actually is outputting the same thing that I currently have. But thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: Your value is in the first capturing group ( highlighted in green in the regex101demo). It does not require a character count.

Comment: Ah I see the difference. However, when I try to match this with my powershell script, it only outputs me the first capturing group.

Comment: @123testing123 Did you try `$matches.Values[1]` See https://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that, maybe an expression similar to,

```
(?<=\\)[^\\]*(?=\\[A-Z0-9]{40}$)
```

might be an option to look into.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/UBV9Vw/1)

Or maybe just,

```
[^\\]*(?=\\[A-Z0-9]{40}$)
```

or

```
[^\\]*(?=\\[A-F0-9]{40}$)
```

would simply return `Root` and 40 is the length of `[A-F0-9]` ending substring. For more flexible quantifier, this expression might work:

```
[^\\]*(?=\\[A-F0-9]*$)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/gAKbkY/1)

Comment: Demo 2 works for me. That's really all I need. But what is the 40 for?

Comment: Does that mean that if its more than 40 characters or less than 40 characters, it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

To offer a pragmatic alternative using PowerShell's [`-split` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375):

```
PS> 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\Root\CDD4EEAE6000AC7F40C3802C171E30148030C072',
'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::CurrentUser\Root\BE36A4562FB2EE05DBB3D32323ADF445084ED656' |
  ForEach-Object { ($_  -split '[::|\\]')[4] }

Root
Root
```

The above tokenizes each input string by separators `\` or `::`, and extracts the 4th token.