# Having problem with split method using powershell

Tags: powershell, split

I have an xml file where i have line some

```
<!--<__AMAZONSITE id="-123456780" instance ="CATZ00124"__/>-->
```

and i need the id and instance values from that particular line.

where i need have `-123456780` as well as  `CATZ00124` in 2 different variables.

Below is the sample code which i have tried

```
$xmlfile = 'D:\Test\sample.xml'
$find_string = '__AMAZONSITE'
$array = @((Get-Content $xmlfile) | select-string $find_string)

Write-Host $array.Length

foreach ($commentedline in $array)
{   
   Write-Host $commentedline.Line.Split('id=')   
}
```

I am getting below result:

```
<!--<__AMAZONSITE 


"-123456780" 
nstance 
"CATZ00124"__/>
```

Comment: Your question appears incomplete and with a number of formatting issue. Could you please have a look into it and improve it a bit? Also, please provide a sample of file Sample.xml to test scripts on.

Comment: The `.split()` method takes every single letter to split, you may want the RegEx based `-split 'id='` operator. But aside from better handling XML files with XML tools you could use a RegEx with capture groups to grep id and instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LotPings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57924005/45375) sensibly recommends using a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) with [*capture groups*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions#groups-captures-and-substitutions) to extract the substrings of interest from each matching line.

You can incorporate that into your [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) call for a single-pipeline solution (the assumption is that the XML comments of interest are all on a single line each):

```
# Define the regex to use with Select-String, which both
# matches the lines of interest and captures the substrings of interest 
# ('id' an 'instance' attributes) via capture groups, (...)
$regex = '<!--<__AMAZONSITE id="(.+?)" instance ="(.+?)"__/>-->'

Select-String -LiteralPath $xmlfile -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {
    # Output a custom object with properties reflecting
    # the substrings of interest reported by the capture groups.
    [pscustomobject] @{
        id = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
        instance = $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value
    }
}
```

The result is an *array of custom objects* that each have an `.id` and `.instance` property with the values of interest (which is preferable to setting individual variables); in the console, the output would look something like this:

```
id         instance
--         --------
-123456780 CATZ00124
-123456781 CATZ00125
-123456782 CATZ00126
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

Note: I'm discussing your use of `.Split()`, though for *extracting a substring*, as is your intent, `.Split()` is not the best tool, given that it is only the first step toward isolating the substring of interest.

As LotPings notes in a comment, **in Windows PowerShell, `$commentedline.Line.Split('id=')` causes the `String.Split()` method to split the input string by *any of the individual characters* in split string `'id='`**, because the method overload that *Windows PowerShell* selects [takes a `char[]` value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___), i.e. an *array of characters*, which is not your intent.

You *could* rectify this as follows, by forcing use of the [overload that accepts `string[]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) (even though you're only passing *one* string), which also requires passing an options argument:

```
$commentedline.Line.Split([string[] 'id=', 'None') # OK, splits by whole string
```

Note that **in PowerShell *Core* the logic is *reversed***, because .NET Core introduced a [new overload with just `[string]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.0#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_) (with an *optional* options argument), which PowerShell Core selects by default. Conversely, this means that **if you *do* want by-any-character splitting in PowerShell Core, you must cast the split string to `[char[]]`**.

On a general note, **PowerShell has the `-split` *operator*, which is *regex*-based and offers much more flexibility than `String.Split()`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).

Applied to your case:

```
$commentedline.Line -split 'id='
```

- While `id=` is interpreted a *regex* by `-split`, that makes no difference here, given that the string contains no regex metacharacters (characters with special meaning); if you do want to safely split by a *literal* substring, use `[regex]::Escape('...')` as the RHS.
- Note that `-split` is case-*insensitive* by default, as PowerShell generally is; however, you can use the `-csplit` variant for case-*sensitive* matching.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way still is to use XML tools for XML files.

As long a line with AMAZONSITE and instance is unique in the file this could do:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\09\13\SO_57923292.ps1

$xmlfile = 'D:\Test\sample.xml' # '.\sample.xml' #

## see following RegEx live and with explanation on https://regex101.com/r/w34ieh/1
$RE = '(?<=AMAZONSITE id=")(?<id>[\d-]+)" instance ="(?<instance>[^"]+)"'

if((Get-Content $xmlfile -raw) -match $RE){
    $AmazonSiteID = $Matches.id
    $Instance     = $Matches.instance
}
```

Comment: Hi @LotPings, Couldnt understand how the regex has to be defined. When through the Regex101.com URL , But couldn't understand how this has to be defined.