# How to store output as a separate variables in windows power shell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to get geolocation of a user based on its IP address and then later using these values further along with the script. I am using this command.

```
$pos=(Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/loc)
```

This command returns me latitude and longitude value separated by a comma (,). as shown below.

```
-20.003,110.009809
```

How can I access/index them separately and store as a separate variable? For example, If I use $pos[1], it does not return me longitude value.

Please also suggest if there is some better way of doing it in windows cmd rather than power shell.

Comment: There is no native Cmd alternative for `Invoke-RestMethod`, so you need to use 3rd party tools such as `curl`. Parsing strings in cmd is quite painful, so why not stick with Powershell?

Comment: The only reason is power shell script requires elevated permissions and requests the user to run the script by adding ".\" to it or suppress this warning by executing a command (set-executionpolicy remotesigned) which is quite scary for a novice user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific to the question *How can I access/index them separately and store as a separate variable?*,
I would consider *not* separate them initially but use the [`GeoCoordinate Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate?view=netframework-4.8) which allows you keep the Latitude/Longitude combined but access separately:

```
Add-type -AssemblyName System.Device
$Geo = New-Object System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate($Pos.Split(','))
$Geo.Latitude
-20.003
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) from a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2" %%a in ('powershell.exe -noprofile -c Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/loc') do set "lat=%%a" & set "long=%%b"

echo Latitude is %lat%, longitude is %long%
```

- Add `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` after `powershell.exe` if you can't be sure that [script execution is enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies) on your system.
- Use `pwsh.exe` instead of `powershell.exe` if you want to use PowerShell *Core* instead of Windows PowerShell.

---

As for [your PowerShell solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58948829/45375):

As a matter of habit, I suggest using PowerShell's `-split` operator rather than the `[string]` type's `.Split()` method, because the regular-expression-based `-split` offers more flexibility and features, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375):

```
$lat, $long = (Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/loc) -split ','
```