# Parse data from log file using Regex patterns

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a log file full of logs of this type :

```
2020-02-04 04:00:31,503 [z4y6480f-214b-4253-9223-n02542f706ac] [INFO] [ServiceType] [ObjectType] - Information about the log
```

I would like, using regex patterns, to retrieve the time, the last text in brackets ([ObjectType] in the exemple) and the information message after the hyphen.

Example of Input :

```
2020-02-04 04:00:33,435 [z4y6480f-214b-4253-9223-n02542f706ac] [INFO] [ServiceTypeJohn] [ObjectTypeJohn] - Information about the John log
2020-02-04 06:50:34,465 [z4y6480f-214b-4253-9223-n02542f706ac] [INFO] [ServiceTypeBob] [ObjectTypeBob] - Information about the Bob log
2020-02-04 07:20:34,677 [z4y6480f-214b-4253-9223-n02542f706ac] [INFO] [ServiceTypeSam] [ObjectTypeSam] - Information about the Sam log
```

Desired output :

```
04:00:33,435 [ObjectTypeJohn] - Information about the John log
06:50:34,465 [ObjectTypeBob] - Information about the Bob log
07:20:34,677 [ObjectTypeSam] - Information about the Sam log
```

So far I have tried this but didn't succeed :

`(Get-Content Output.txt) -replace '^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).*(\[.*?\] - .*?)$','$1;$2'`

Would appreciate any help on this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(Get-Content Output.txt) -replace '^\S+\s+(\S+).*(\[[^][]*])\s*(-.*)', '$1 $2 $3'
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cS%2b%5cs%2b%28%5cS%2b%29.*%28%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%29%5cs*%28-.*%29&i=2020-02-04+04%3a00%3a33%2c435+%5bz4y6480f-214b-4253-9223-n02542f706ac%5d+%5bINFO%5d+%5bServiceTypeJohn%5d+%5bObjectTypeJohn%5d+-+Information+about+the+John+log%0d%0a2020-02-04+06%3a50%3a34%2c465+%5bz4y6480f-214b-4253-9223-n02542f706ac%5d+%5bINFO%5d+%5bServiceTypeBob%5d+%5bObjectTypeBob%5d+-+Information+about+the+Bob+log%0d%0a2020-02-04+07%3a20%3a34%2c677+%5bz4y6480f-214b-4253-9223-n02542f706ac%5d+%5bINFO%5d+%5bServiceTypeSam%5d+%5bObjectTypeSam%5d+-+Information+about+the+Sam+log&r=%241+%242+%243&o=m)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `\S+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: 1+ chars other than whitespace
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than newline, as many as possible
- `(\[[^][]*])` - Group 2: `[`, 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char
- `\s*` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(-.*)` - Group 3: `-` and the rest of the string.

Demo results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! Could you please also show how to retrieve the brackets of [ServiceType] instead of [ObjectType] ?

Comment: @Kimo [Like this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cS%2b%5cs%2b%28%5cS%2b%29.*%28%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%29%5cs%2b%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%5cs%2b%28-.*%29&i=2020-02-04+04%3a00%3a33%2c435+%5bz4y6480f-214b-4253-9223-n02542f706ac%5d+%5bINFO%5d+%5bServiceTypeJohn%5d+%5bObjectTypeJohn%5d+-+Information+about+the+John+log&r=%241+%242+%243&o=m).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to a regex solution, consider use of the unary form of the [`-split` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375), which makes for a conceptually simpler solution:

```
(Get-Content Output.txt).ForEach({ 
  # Split line into an array of fields by whitespace.
  $fields = -split $_ 
  # Extract the fields of interest by index and re-join with spaces.
  $fields[1, 5 + 6..($fields.Count-1)] -join ' ' 
})
```

The unary form of `-split` behaves similar to the Unix `awk` utility, in that it tokenizes a line by any runs of non-empty whitespace, ignoring leading and trailing whitespace).

Note that the solution above relies on the fields before the `-` not containing whitespace themselves, which is true for the sample input.