# Is there a reason why .split in PowerShell doesn't work for me?

Tags: string, powershell, split

```
$fID = Read-Host "Enter URL" 

if($fID -Match "/"){

$fID = $fID.split("/")[1].split(".")[0]

}

$fID[1]
```

input: `https://split.string.com` (for example)

what i want is just "**split**"

output: *nothing*

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Your problem is not your split ... ;-)   `$fID = $fID.split("/")[1].split(".")[0]` should be `$fID = $fID.split("/")[2].split(".")[0]` ... and `$fID[1]` should be `$fID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that separator `/` splits by *every occurrence* of `/` int the input string so that the `//` in `https://split.string.com` results in an *extra, empty* element in the resulting array of tokens (the empty string between the two `/` chars.), which is what index `[1]` returns.

In **PowerShell [Core] 6+, simply use `//` as the separator**:

```
PSCore> 'https://split.string.com'.split('//')[1].split('.')[0]
split
```

This doesn't work in **Windows PowerShell**, however, because splitting by a single `[string]` instance isn't supported by the underlying .NET Framework (instead, its *individual characters* are interpreted as separators).

There, you can simply take the extra, empty element into account and adjust the index accordingly, as [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) suggests:

```
WinPS> 'https://split.string.com'.split('/')[2].split('.')[0]
split
```

<sup>Note: Eliminating the empty entry via an optional argument works too, but is both verbose and obscure: `'https://split.string.com'.split('/', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].Split('.')[0]`</sup>

---

The **alternative** is to **use PowerShell's *regex-based* [`-split` *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)**, which is **generally preferable to the `[string]` type's `.Split()` *method*** and works in both PowerShell editions:

```
PS> ('https://split.string.com' -split '//|\.')[1]
split
```

<sup>[Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `//|\.` matches either (`|`) string `//` or a literal `.` (escaped as `\.`, because `.` by itself has special meaning in a regex).</sup>

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375) for background information, including why sticking with PowerShell-native features guards against inadvertent behavioral changes due to new .NET method overloads getting introduced later.

Answer (score 1):

To compliment the comprehensive answer from [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) on the actual "**why**" question:
I would take this from a different angle and start from the [**`host`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.uri.host?view=netframework-4.8#System_Uri_Host) property of the [**`uri`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8) class:

```
# $fID = [uri](Read-Host "Enter URL" )
$fID = [uri]'https://split.string.com'

$fID.Host.Split('.')[0]
```

**yields**

```
 split
```