# Powershell: Folder Structure from csv List, Problem with share rights

Tags: powershell, split

I'm writing a powershell script that creates folders and rights from a csv list.
the script is almost done, only one issue I can't seem to get around.
one column is for account names (for the share rights), when I enter on name it works, when I go for more than one it doesn't, now when I try it manulally it works, the only problem is with powershell understanding the cell value in that column
the cell value looks like this  `"Account1" , "Account2"` 
now this works just fine when I type it in manually, it just seems as if powershell isn't interpreting the coma as a seperator when it's imported from the list, I guess it's being interpreted as a part of a string.
This is the share rights Code `New-SmbShare -Name $dir1 -Path $loc1 -FullAccess $share1`
this is the error I get when I run the Script `"No mapping between account names and security IDs was done"`
can someone please offer a solution?
Thanks

Comment: You're correct that PowerShell interprets the contents as a string literal, it won't convert it to an array for you automatically. But you can easily do that yourself like this: '"abcd","efg"'.split(",") | %{$_.trim('"')}

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that there is a many-to-many relationship between folders and users.  You would have an analogous problem if you tried to do the same thing in a single SQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`New-SmbShare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbshare)'s `-FullAccess` parameter is typed as `[string[]]`, i.e. as an *array* of strings (verify with `Get-Help New-SmbShare -Parameter FullAccess`).

However, in your case `"Account1" , "Account2"` is the verbatim content of a *single* string (as you would get with `$share1 = '"Account1" , "Account2"'`) that can be *interpreted* as an array, but you'll have to do that interpretation yourself, as [JonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612620/jonc) points out:

```
New-SmbShare -Name $dir1 -Path $loc1 -FullAccess ($share1 -split '[", ]' -ne '')
```

- `$share1 -split '[", ]'` splits the string by any occurrence of characters `"`, `,` or   (space) into tokens; note that this assumes that account names have no embedded spaces, but that is usually safe to assume.

  - You can read more about the regex-based `-split` operator in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).
- `-ne ''` filters out empty-string tokens from the resulting array, so that you'll end up with array `'Account1', 'Account2'`, as intended.

---

Note that you may be tempted to use `Invoke-Expression $share1`, but `Invoke-Expression` should generally be the *last resort*, due to its security risks: only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)