# WOL works outside of Powershell

Tags: powershell, wake-on-lan

Regardless of what Script I use I can not get PowerShell 5.1 to trigger a boot on my Hyper-V Host.

I can use the solarwinds WakeonLan tool to boot the server, but I would like to find a solution that would work natively.

I tried many scripts I had found online and as a last ditch effort, I installed the "[WakeOnLAN 1.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WakeOnLan/1.0)" Module but while it says it executes successfully the server does not boot

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Invoke-WakeOnLan 52:a4:4c:52:d7:52 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Wake-on-Lan Packet sent to 52:a4:4c:52:d7:52
```

What could cause the server only to boot with the SolarWinds WakeOnLan.exe but not natively in Powershell?

As it may be relevant the computer I am attempting to send the MagicPacket from is a MultiNic Machine but only 1 NIC is IP'd on the subnet of the Hyper-V server.

Other Scripts I attempted to use:

- https://www.pdq.com/blog/wake-on-lan-wol-magic-packet-powershell/
- https://powershell.one/code/11.html

Comment: Did you try quoting the MAC address?

Comment: Are you using Windows PowerShell (up to version 5.1) or PowerShell (Core) (v6+)?

Comment: @zett42, the code uses `.Split('-:')`, which works like `.Split([char[]] '-:')` (as intended) in WinPS, but like `.Split([string]'-:')` in PS Core - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375)

Comment: Yes I tried both single and double quotes as well as : and - separators. 
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.610
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.610
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: Usually wake on lan only works on the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me with remote powershell, going to the same subnet the down computers are on.  Fast startup also has to be disabled in the windows 10 registry (HiberbootEnabled=0).

```
$mac = @{comp002 = '00:11:22:33:44:55'; comp003 = '00:11:22:33:44:56'}
$compsDown = 'comp002','comp003'
# (,) is silly workaround to pass array as invoke-command arguments
icm comp001 invoke-wakeonlan.ps1 -args (,$mac[$compsDown])
```