# Powershell split on different objects

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to create a script that will split on various object. For example I have disks name

```
vm01-disk1
vm01_disk2
```

I'm trying to split the disk names so I can rename the disk vm, but retain the disk number, what I've tried is

```
 $snapshot = Get-AzSnapShot
 $vhdlong = ($snapshot.name).Split("_")[0]
 $vhdrename = $vhdlong.split("-")[1]
```

But this still leaves vm01_disk2 untouched, if I add `$vhdrename = $vhdlong.split("_")[1]` it leaves vm01-disk1 untouched.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance for any tips or advice :)

Comment: Seems like you just need to loop through `$snapshot.name`.

Comment: If `Get-AzSnapShot` returns more than one object (an array of snapshots) I'd rather use a loop to process whatever you need.  ;-)

Comment: The (string) `.Split()` method accepts more character/string separators in an array. Try `.Split([char[]]'-_')`. Check _OverloadDefinitions_ using `''.Split`.

Comment: `'ab_cd-ef' -split '_|-'`

Comment: Thanks All. That's really helpful, I think JosefZ hit the nail on the head and works perfectly If you'd like to mark it as an answer I'll accept it, thanks again all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Unless performance is paramount, I suggest routinely using PowerShell's [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator, for the reasons discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).

  - Splitting by *any* from a *set* of characters can be expressed as enclosing these characters in `[...]` in a regex; in the case at hand: `[-_]`
- The [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) enables a (fairly) efficient way to operate on each element of a collection of values already in memory.

Therefore, I suggest the following:

```sh
(Get-AzSnapShot).Name.ForEach({ ($_ -split '[-_]')[1] })
```