# question about powershell text manipulation

Tags: powershell

I apologise for asking the very basic question as I am beginner in Scripting.
i was wondering why i am getting different result from two different source with the same formatting. Below are my sample

file1.txt

```
 Id Name                      Members                      
122 RCP_VMWARE-DMZ-NONPROD    DMZ_NPROD01_111        
                              DMZ_NPROD01_113        
123 RCP_VMWARE-DMZ-PROD       DMZ_PROD01_110         
                              DMZ_PROD01_112         
124 RCP_VMWARE-DMZ-INT.r87351 DMZ_TEMPL_210.r        
                              DMZ_DECOM_211.r        
125 RCP_VMWARE-LAN-NONPROD    NPROD02_20             
                              NPROD03_21             
                              NPROD04_22             
                              NPROD06_24
```

file2.txt

```
Id Name       Members             
4  HPUX_PROD HPUX_PROD.3
             HPUX_PROD.4
             HPUX_PROD.5
```

i'm trying to display the Name column and with this code i'm able to display the file1.txt correctly.

```
PS C:\Share> gc file1.txt |Select-Object -skip 1 | foreach-object { $_.split(" ")[1]} | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" }
RCP_VMWARE-DMZ-NONPROD
RCP_VMWARE-DMZ-PROD
RCP_VMWARE-DMZ-INT.r87351
RCP_VMWARE-LAN-NONPROD
```

However with the file2 im getting a different output.

```
PS C:\Share> gc .\file2.txt |Select-Object -skip 1 | foreach-object { $_.split(" ")[1]} | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" }
4

changing the code to *$_.split(" ")[2]}* helps to display the output correctly
```

However, i would like to have just 1 code which can be apply for both situation.appreciate if you can help me to sort this.. thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answers are helpful, but let me try to break it down conceptually:

- **`.Split(" ")` splits the input string by *each individual* space character**, whereas what you're looking for is to split by *runs* of (one or more) spaces, given that your column values can be separated by more than one space.

  - For instance `'a  b'.split(' ')` results in *3* array elements - `'a'`, `''`, `'b'` - because the *empty string* between the *two* spaces is considered an element too.
- **The .NET `[string]` type's [`.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Split) *method* is based on *verbatim* strings or *character sets* and therefore doesn't allow you to express the concept of "one ore more spaces" as a split criterion, whereas PowerShell's [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-split` *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) does**.

  - Conveniently, **`-split`'s *unary* form (see below) has this logic built in: it splits each input string by any *nonempty run of whitespace***, while also ignoring leading and trailing whitespace, which in your case obviates the need for a regex altogether.
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375) compares and contrasts the `-split` operator with string type's `.Split()` method, and makes the case for *routinely* using the former.

Therefore, a working solution (for both input files) is:

```
Get-Content .\file2.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
  Foreach-Object { if ($value = (-split $_)[1]) { $value } }
```

Note:

- If the column of interest contains a value (at least one non-whitespace character), so must all *preceding* columns in order for the approach to work. Also, column values themselves must not have *embedded* whitespace (which is true for your sample input).
- The `if` conditional both extracts the 2nd column value (`(-split $_)[1]`) and assigns it to a variable (`$value =` ), whose value then implicitly serves as a Boolean:

  - Any *nonempty* string is implicitly `$true`, in which case the extracted value is output in the associated block (`{ $value }`); conversely, an *empty* string results in *no* output.
  - For a general overview of PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversions, see this bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the latter file has different format.

When examined carefully, one notices there are two spaces between `4` and `HPUX_PROD` strings:

```
Id Name       Members             
4  HPUX_PROD HPUX_PROD.3
^^^^
```

On the first file, there is a single space between number and string:

```
 Id Name                      Members                      
122 RCP_VMWARE-DMZ-NONPROD    DMZ_NPROD01_111 
  ^^^
```

As how to fix the issue depends if you need to match both file formats, or if the other has simply a typing error.

Answer (score 1):

Since this sort-of looks like csv output with spaces as delimiter (but not quite), I think you could use `ConvertFrom-Csv` on this:

```
# read the file as string array, trim each line and filter only the lines that
# when split on 1 or more whitespace characters has more than one field
# then replace the spaces by a comma and treat it as CSV
# return the 'Name' column only
(((Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\file1.txt').Trim() | 
    Where-Object { @($_ -split '\s+').Count -gt 1 }) -replace '\s+', ',' | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv).Name
```

Shorter, but because you are only after the Name column, this works too:

```
((Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\file2.txt').Trim() -replace '\s+', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv).Name -ne ''
```

Output for file1

```
RCP_VMWARE-DMZ-NONPROD
RCP_VMWARE-DMZ-PROD
RCP_VMWARE-DMZ-INT.r87351
RCP_VMWARE-LAN-NONPROD
```

Output for file2

```
HPUX_PROD
```