# PowerShell - Can’t Split String

Tags: powershell

I suddenly can’t seem to split a string, which I’ve done successfully before. The string is a list of exclusions for **Get-ChildItem**, which I want to display in a more readable format so the user can easily verify they’re correct.

I’m using PowerShell 7.3.4. The code:

```
# Regular expression of files/folders to exclude from the search
   $exclusions =  "\.bak| - Copy|\.db|\.ini|\.log|\.temp|template|test|\.tmp|New-Folder|prototype|_vti"
   $substrings = $exclusions -split "|"
   $substrings
   $count      = $substrings.count
   Write-Host "Number of exclusions: $count"
   foreach ($string in $substrings) {
         Write-Host "► $_"
   }
```

The only output correctly says “Number of exclusions: 12,” but never shows them.

The backslashes tell the regular expression parser to treat the periods literally. Could the backslashes be interfering with the -Split call?

Comment: `get-childitem -exclude *.bak,'* - Copy',*.db,*.ini`

Comment: Alternatively use `String.Split()`, which doesn't use RegEx: `$substrings = $exclusions.Split('|')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- You need to escape `|` in the regex pattern, eg. `... -split '\|'`
- You're using `$string` as an iterator variable, but reference `$_` in the loop

Fix both problems and it'll work as expected:

```
$exclusions =  "\.bak| - Copy|\.db|\.ini|\.log|\.temp|template|test|\.tmp|New-Folder|prototype|_vti"
$substrings = $exclusions -split "\|"
$count      = $substrings.count
Write-Host "Number of exclusions: $count"
foreach ($string in $substrings) {
    Write-Host "► $string"
}
```

Output:

```
Number of exclusions: 12
► \.bak
►  - Copy
► \.db
► \.ini
► \.log
► \.temp
► template
► test
► \.tmp
► New-Folder
► prototype
► _vti
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76347760/45375) with more detailed background information (focusing just on the `-split` operation):

By default, PowerShell's **[`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)** interprets its **separator operand** as a **[regex (regular expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)**.

Therefore, **regex [metacharacters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) such as `|` that you want to use *verbatim* must be *escaped***:

- Either: **metacharacter-individually** with **`\`**:

  ```bash
  'a|b|c' -split '\|'  # -> @('a', 'b', 'c')
  ```
- Or - in order to **treat an *entire string / unknown character* verbatim** - with **[`[regex]::Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace)**:

  ```bash
  'a|b|c' -split [regex]::Escape('|')
  ```

**Alternatively**, use the (rarely used) **`SimpleMatch` option** with `-split`:

- Somewhat awkwardly, you then also need to specify the normally optionally second operand that specifies *how many tokens to limit the results to*; `0` signifies the default behavior of returning *all* tokens.

  ```bash
  'a|b|c' -split '|', 0, 'SimpleMatch'
  ```

**Another alternative** is to use the **`[string]` type's [`.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Split) *.NET method***, which ***invariably* treats its separator character(s) / strings *verbatim***, and therefore doesn't require escaping:

```bash
# See caveat below re using (multi-character) *strings* as separators.
'a|b|c'.Split('|')
```

- In the case at hand that is arguably the simplest solution; however, there are **caveats**:

  - The separator is *invariably* matched case-*sensitively*, whereas `-split` is case-*insensitive* by default (as all PowerShell operators are), with the `-csplit` variant offering case-sensitivity when needed.
  - In order to split by a *string* as opposed to a *single* character or by any one from an *array* of characters, you must use the following non-obvious form in *Windows PowerShell*:

    ```bash
    # !! The [string[]] cast and the 0 argument are necessary
    # !! in Windows PowerShell, because .Split('||') would be 
    # !! the same as .Split([char[]] '||'), and therefore split by *each* '|'
    'a||b||c'.Split([string[]] '||', 0)
    ```

    - A new method overload in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) makes this no longer necessary, but this change in behavior - outside of PowerShell's control - illustrates a pitfall with the long-term stability of .NET method calls from PowerShell: unless you *precisely* type all arguments to match the method signature, PowerShell's automatic type conversions can end up selecting a *different* method overload as new overloads are added by .NET.
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375) juxtaposes `-split` and `.Split()` in detail, and makes the case to routinely prefer `-split`, except in rare cases where  performance dictates otherwise.

Comment: Does anyone know how to prevent the forum software from interpreting an Enter key as if I hit the "Add Comment" Key? I can't enter more than a single paragraph now, which makes things very hard to read.

Comment: @aksarben, comments by design don't support line breaks - the next comment provides a summary of the limitations:

Comment: As for formatting in comments: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - in short: you can only use _inline_ code formatting (`\`...\``) with no support for line breaks. Unlike in posts, there must be _no whitespace_ after the opening and before the closing delimiter. _Multi_-`\`` delimiters for support of embedded `\`` chars. are supported (e.g. `\`\`"\`n"\`\``). Unlike in posts, ``\`` can alternatively be used to escape `\``, which, due to the no-whitespace requirement, is a must if you want to produce something like `\`enclosed\``. To produce a formatted ``\`` alone, use `\`\`\\`\``