# What is the equivalent of str.Substring in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, substring

I'm making a simple compiling tool as a way to practice PS, and I need to extract a part of the string into another variable. For example:

`[string]$Filepath = "C:/Users/xxx/Projects/file.cpp"`
(I need the last part of the string)

Since I'm a beginner at PS, is there a way to possibly do this without using a regex?

I tried the `-match` thing but I'm not looking for any specific value, I just need everything after the last "/".

Comment: `Split-Path`?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, should've clarified. I'm not working with an actual path, just a string that the user inputs. Would this still work with a string?

Comment: Would it hurt you when you tried? ;-)

Comment: @Olaf No idea, should've read more docs first

Comment: How long would that take?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`  `Split-Path -Path $Filepath -Leaf`

Comment: @Olaf Wow, okay. Yeah I'm not very good at PS.

Comment: Please always read the help for the cmdlets you're about to use completely including the exmaples to learn how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question contained in your post's *title*:

> What is the equivalent of str.Substring in PowerShell?

PowerShell offers virtually unlimited access to all .NET APIs, so you're free to call the [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String) type's [`.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Substring) directly; e.g.:

```bash
# -> 'file.cpp'
"C:/Users/xxx/Projects/file.cpp".Substring(22)
```

---

> I just need everything after the last "/".

Similarly, you can use the .NET [`.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Split) method to split a string by a given, *verbatim* character and combine it with *PowerShell's enhanced indexing* to allow you to reference elements *from the end*, using *negative indices*, notably `[-1]` to refer to the *last* element of an array (as well as other .NET types implementing the [`System.Collections.IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IList) interface).

```bash
# -> 'file.cpp'
"C:/Users/xxx/Projects/file.cpp".Split('/')[-1]
```

---

PowerShell itself offers the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) *operator*, whose RHS, the split criterion, is interpreted as a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) by default (with `/` that doesn't make a difference):

```bash
# -> 'file.cpp'
("C:/Users/xxx/Projects/file.cpp" -split '/')[-1]
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375) for why using `-split` over `.Split()` is generally preferable, considering the tradeoffs involved.

---

Another option is to use PowerShell's regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator; the following uses a regex to match everything up to the *last* `/` character and - due to not specifying a *substitution operand* - effectively *removes* what was matched, leaving only what comes *after* the last `/`:

```bash
# -> 'file.cpp'
"C:/Users/xxx/Projects/file.cpp" -replace '^.*/'
```

For a comprehensive but concise summary of `-replace`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

---

Finally, *only with separators `/` and* `\`, you can use the [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path) cmdlet's `-Leaf` parameter, taking advantage of the fact that PowerShell recognizes `\` and `/` *interchangeably* as path (directory) separators:

```bash
# -> 'file.cpp'
Split-Path -Leaf "C:/Users/xxx/Projects/file.cpp"
```