# How to get the index of the last occurence of a char in PowerShell string?

Tags: powershell

I want to get the index of the last "\" occurrence in order to trim the "Activity" word and keep it, from following string in PowerShell:

```
$string = "C:\cmb_Trops\TAX\Auto\Activity"
```

I'm converting the code from VBScript to PowerShell and in VB there's this solution :

```
Right(string, Len(string) - InStrRev(string, "\"))
```

Using Right and InStrRev functions which makes the life more easier. Unfortunately I didn't find anything like it in PowerShell. Can't find any option to scan from the end of the string.

Comment: PowerShell is .NET based, and `String` has `LastIndexOf`, so `.LastIndexOf('\')` would do. But what you're probably *really* after is `Split-Path` (and the other cmdlets PowerShell has for path parsing).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string with powershell to get the first and last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095674/split-a-string-with-powershell-to-get-the-first-and-last-element)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$String.Split("\")[-1]
```

Or if `$String` is actually a real path, you might consider:

```
Split-Path $String -Leaf
```

Comment: Even if it's not a real path, but follows a path syntax, you could use the `System.IO.Path` class: `[IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path)` (alternatively, `GetFileName`)

Answer (score 8):

```
$string = "C:\cmb_Trops\TAX\Auto\Activity"
$string = $string.Substring($string.lastIndexOf('\') + 1)
echo $string
```

Check out:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1330191-powershell-remove-all-text-after-last-instance-of

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I wasn't precise at what I wrote. I want the opposite. Keep only the "Activity"  and eliminate everything else.

Comment: `$string = $string.Substring($string.lastIndexOf('\') + 1)` Sorry, you were clear; I just misread :)

Comment: @CrazyCranberry I suggest you edit your answewr to contain the corrected version - so follow up readers don't have to sieve through comments.