# How to Remove Everything after the last Slash in a Path Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to remove everything after and including the last slash in a CanonicalName.  As you might expect that amount of letters, characters, words and the length are variable.  Which is why I need to use the fact that everything after the last slash "/" is the only thing each one has in common.

I'm using the following:

```
(Get-ADUser Identity USER -Properties *).CanonicalName
```

Normal output would be something like:

```
domain.tld/dept/section/office/USER
```

What I would like the result to be is:

```
domain.tld/dept/section/office
```

Eventually this will be incorporated into for loop and run through thousands of users which is why I need to find a way to strip off the end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382576/how-to-get-the-index-of-the-last-occurence-of-a-char-in-powershell-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
(Get-ADUser Identity USER -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName -replace '/[^/]*$'
```

`/` matches literal `/`. `[^]` is a negated character class making `[^/]` match anything but `/`. `*` is zero or more matches quantifier (greedily matching). `$` is the end of string.

---

Path conversions do work as well, but if your platform's directory separator char is not `/`, then the `/` will be converted to something else. Then you will be left with converting them back. It is just more work than using the simple `-replace` operator.